# __aenter__() is not working for binance socket manager

Tags: python, binance-api-client

I am using binance socket manager but I think ****aenter**()** magic method replaced with something else. its not working.

This is my code:

```
import os
import time

import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client
from binance import BinanceSocketManager

api_key = os.environ.get('binance_api_key')
api_secret = os.environ.get('binance_api_secret')


client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

socket = bsm.trade_socket('BTCUSDT')

await socket.__aenter__()
msg = await socket.recv()
print(msg)
```

This is the error:

```
await socket.__aenter__()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

Comment: Change to `async with socket:` `msg = await socket.recv()`. I don't understand where you got that you should directly invoke `__aenter__`.

Comment: Tried not working.

Comment: `await` has to be used inside `async function` - you can't use it directly. And it will need to run some `async loop`

Comment: documentation shows [BinanceSocketManager Websocket Usage](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html#binancesocketmanager-websocket-usage)

Answer (score 0):

`await` has to be used inside `async function` - you can't use it directly.
And it needs to run some `async loop`.

Documentation even shows how to do it: [BinanceSocketManager Websocket Usage](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html#binancesocketmanager-websocket-usage)

BTW: it seems `trade_socket` runs even without `API key`.

```py
#import os
import asyncio
from binance.client import Client
from binance import BinanceSocketManager

# PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` for constants
#API_KEY    = os.environ.get('binance_api_key')
#API_SECRET = os.environ.get('binance_api_secret')

async def main():
    #client = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
    client = Client()
    
    bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

    socket = bsm.trade_socket('BTCUSDT')

    async with socket as ts:
        while True:
            msg = await ts.recv()
            print(msg)

# ---

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Now I get another error.
TypeError: As of 3.10, the *loop* parameter was removed from Queue() since it is no longer necessary

Comment: if you have problem with new code then create new question on new page - and you will have place to show code. Python 3.10 is very new version and some modules may not be ready for this version - so sometimes it is better use older version and wait few months. I still use 3.8 but I have also installed 3.9 and 3.10

Comment: Ok. I am trying older version.

Comment: I tested on 3.10 and it really have problem because of some changes in standard modules in 3.10 - so you may need to use 3.9 or you may have to wait for new `binance` for 3.10

Comment: it seems someone already send message to authors of `binance: [Incompatible with Python 3.10 · Issue #1150 · sammchardy/python-binance](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/1150)

Comment: Yes . Its working on 3.8 python. @furas thanks dear. Can I get a chance to work with you. Please add that working in the answer ans I will accept the answer.